# Set of convergent sequences is open in $B(\mathbb{N}, M)$ if M is discrete

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

"If the metric space $M$ is discrete then the set of convergent sequences is open in $B(\mathbb{N},M)$."

Here,  $B(\mathbb{N},M)$ is the space of bounded functions $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow M$ with the sup metric.

My approach was taking an arbitrary sequence ($x_{n}$ being $x: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow M$) from the set of convergent sequences (call it **$C$**) and showing that it converges to a point **a** in M (which is isolated). So there exists a radius $r>0$ s.t. $B(a,r) = {a}$, that is, $lim x_{n}=a$ is an interior point. But the metric space $M$ has only isolated points, in such a way that the totality of sequences in the set **$C$** converge to interior points.

From this point, I would try to use that since each point is interior, $C$ would be open in $B(\mathbb{N},M)$. Which is something I can't do, because I know that the **limits** of the sequences are interior points, not the sequences themselves, so I can't compare. What should I do now? Use something like the sup metric on $C$ or something alike? Any hints are appreciated. I'm not looking for a different proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, for your $r$ you will have that
$$
B(f,r) \subseteq \{g \in B(\mathbb N,M) \mid \lim g = a\} \subseteq \{g \in B(\mathbb N,M) \mid \text{$g$ converges}\},
$$
because any sequence that converges to an isolated value $a$ must simply take the value $a$ at some point and keep taking it, and any function that does not must always keep taking values different from $a$, that is, values with distance more than $r$ from $a$.